# Why new Date() won't render inside a JSX element (React)

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to render an `h1` and `h2` containing the current date using `new Date()` inside curly braces in JSX but it doesn't show *anything*.

Here's my code:

```js
function tick() {
  const APP = (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
      <h2>It is {new Date()}.</h2>
    </div>
  );

  ReactDOM.render(APP,document.getElementById('root'))
}

tick();
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Look in the JavaScript console in your browser's web developer tools. What do you see?

Comment: You can check the working implementation here https://codepen.io/marudhupandiyang/pen/vdavXm

Comment: Thank you I get it

Comment: Updated answer based on Panther's fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date is a JavaScript object. If you want it to work, you need it in a different format, like a string

```
function tick() {
  const APP = (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
      <h2>It is {(new Date()).toLocaleString()}.</h2>
    </div>
  );
  ReactDOM.render(APP,document.getElementById('root'))
}

tick();
```

It's also worth mentioning that `APP` is the perfect candidate for a React component. Try making it into a functional or class based component

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
      <h2>It is {new Date().toString()}.</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Yeah, but aren't we in the JS context by wrapping the code in curly braces??

Comment: Yes you are, but a browser doesn't know how to render objects! A new date object is an object. However, a browser does know how to render strings of text

Comment: If this answer helped answer you question, could you accept it so people know what to do if they have the same problem? :)

Comment: Done. One more thing why when I omit the toString , nothing appear even the h1 element

Comment: Without the toString, you are attempting to render a Date object to the browser, which it doesn't know how to render.

Comment: I know that now, but why does it affect the h1 element , shouldn't it render h1 correctly regardless of the h2 which contains the Date object ??

Comment: Because trying to render an object causes an error (Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child), which is causing you entire page to not render.

Answer (score 0):

Becasuse new Date it's an object

```
function tick() {
      const APP = (
        <div>
          <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
          <h2>It is {new Date().toString()}.</h2>
        </div>
      );
        ReactDOM.render(APP,document.getElementById('root'))
    }

    tick();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you open up the console, you should see a fairly descriptive error:

`Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: This is a JS code wrapped in curly braces not an object. Correct me if I'm wrong